# How to find the matches between two columns in Excel sheet?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

In Microsoft Excel 2010, I have an excel sheet that has two columns Z and AG. Z has 11400 rows and AG has 3000 rows. I want to find the matches between both of them in a new column. So how to do that? 
I tried the following formula:

```
=IF(MAX(COUNTIF($AG$2:$AG$114000,$Z$2:$Z$114000))>1,"Duplicate","Nope")
```

But it did not work correctly with me because it gave me "Nope" for all the rows, however i have many matches between both of them.

**So could you please help me with this?**

Answer (score 3):

If the results can be sparse (empty rows in result set), then I would use vlookups. The formula would look something like this:

```
=vlookup(ag2,$z$2:$z$114000,1,false)
```

Copy that down to every entry in az and it should give you the matches.

Comment: Thank you for your help but is there any way to highlight the matches in Column Z? Because I want to see the data on the other columns that are related to the matched data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier to use conditional formatting. For example you could apply a formula for conditional formatting that is something like this:

```
=COUNTIF($AG$1:$AG$114000,Z1)>1
```

You could set the formatting to be highlight the cell, and then copy the formatting down column Z. I think that should work. User this website for reference: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/highlight-duplicates.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this formula ...it works good

A - FIRST COLUMN C IS ANOTHER COLUMN B IS EMPTY COLUMN WHERE YOU WANT TO POPULATE THE COMMON DATA

=if(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,C1....C30,0)),""A1)