# How to sort and arrange this excel sheet based on the matching results?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a big excel sheet. I added one column to it in AG and then I did a matching between this column AG that has 3000 rows and the column Z that has 114000 rows. The matched results have been put on the column AI using this formula:

```
=vlookup(ag2,$z$2:$z$114000,1,false)
```

What I want now is the following: I want rearrange the sheet based on the results on the new column but I want to see the data on the the columns that are related to the each cell in the Matching results document. **So how to do that?**

What I did is highlight the whole sheet and sort it based on the new column AI. However, it did not give me the related data on the other columns so how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your previous question and seeing this new question, I might suggest with looking at conditional formatting or a large sort. The previous question is [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787487/how-to-find-the-matches-between-two-columns-in-excel-sheet).

The conditional formatting can be done on your "helper" column, AI, or on column Z as you had posed in the previous question. Apply red, for example, when AI is 1. How to found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx). The second thing is a [multi-level sort](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-sort-excel-2010-data-on-multiple-columns.html) which it sounds like you tried.

Although I think based on the part where you say "Matching results document", you are looking to put the actual matching results in AI, try `=INDEX($z$2:$z$114000,MATCH(ag2,$z$2:$z$114000,0))`. Anything with #N/A means it doesn't have a match.